# Mapping a cube to a sphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, projective-geometry

I have been looking for a way to map a unit cube (with vertices $x^2=1$,  $y^2=1$,  $z^2=1$) to a unit sphere ($x^2+y^2+z^2=1$) with minimal distortion of the great circles formed by mapping the coordinate lines on the cube face. As can be seen from the following picture, a simple radial contraction onto the sphere surface leads to large visible distortion of the great circles.

[image: Radial contraction onto sphere]

Phil Nowell [here](https://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html?lr=1) derived an elegant mapping that generates a much more uniform subdivision of the great circles.

[image: Nowell mapping]

However, close inspection shows that there is still some room for improvement. Points near the center of the cube faces get more compressed than those near the edges.

By using the rotation of central planes to map points on the cube to equidistant points on the sphere, I was able to come up with the following expressions for an improved mapping:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_\text{sphere}=x_c/\sqrt{x_c^2+ y_c^2+ z_c^2}\\
y_\text{sphere}=y_c/\sqrt{x_c^2+ y_c^2 + z_c^2}\\
z_\text{sphere}=z_c/\sqrt{x_c^2+ y_c^2 + z_c^2}
\end {cases}
$$

where
$$
\begin{cases}
x_c=\sqrt{x^p+y^2+z^2} \tan\left(x  \arctan\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^p+y^2+z^2} } \right)\right)\\
y_c=\sqrt{x^2+y^p+z^2} \tan\left(y  \arctan\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^p+z^2} } \right)\right)\\
z_c=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^p} \tan\left(z\arctan\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^p} } \right)\right)
\end{cases}
$$

- $p$ is a large even integer and
- $x$, $y$, $z$ are the coordinates of the cube.

The picture below is obtained with $p=50$

[image: Improved mapping]

To express the quality $Q$ of the mapping, I calculate the ratio of the maximum and minimum length of a line segment on the most distorted great circle, $i,$ as follows:
$$
Q=\frac{\ell_{i,\min}}{\ell_{i,\max}} \cdot 100\% 
$$
so that an optimum distribution gives a quality of $100\%.$

With this, the quality of the radial contraction of the 9x9x9 grid depicted above becomes $58\%,$ that of Nowell’s mapping becomes $79\%$ and that of my improved mapping becomes $96\%.$ It is also worth noting that the quality on the central coordinate lines and the edges is $100\%.$

Now, my question is: “can my mapping be improved further to yield a quality of $100\%$ everywhere on the sphere?”

*Update 1*

The following iterative scheme gives a further improvement:
$$
\begin{align}
x_{c,0} &= x,\quad  y_{c,0} = y,\quad  z_{c,0} = z\\
x_{c,i+1} &=\sqrt{x^{p}_{c,i}+y^{2}_{c,i}+z^{2}_{c,i}} \tan\left(x\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{p}_{c,i}+y^{2}_{c,i}+z^{2}_{c,i}} } \right)\right)\\ 
y_{c,i+1} &=\sqrt{x^{2}_{c,i}+y^{p}_{c,i}+z^{2}_{c,i}} \tan\left(y\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}_{c,i}+y^{p}_{c,i}+z^{2}_{c,i}} } \right)\right)\\ z_{c,i+1} &=\sqrt{x^{2}_{c,i}+y^{2}_{c,i}+z^{p}_{c,i}} \tan\left(z\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}_{c,i}+y^{2}_{c,i}+z^{p}_{c,i}} } \right)\right) 
\end{align} 
$$
With this, the quality of the mapped 9x9x9 grid increases after 2 iterations from 96.1% to 97.7%

For finer grids the improvement is more pronounced. A 50x50x50 grid (with p=500) achieves an improvement from 95.3% to 97.1% after 1 iteration and a grid of 500x500x500 (with p=5000) shows an improvement from 95.2% to 97.0% with 1 iteration.

Comment: The question of mapping a portion of a sphere to the plane has been well studied due to its application to map projection. In that context, it's well known that no such map can represent all lengths in their correct proportions. My favorite text in this field is [Portraits of the Earth](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/mawrld-18), where this result is attributed to Euler. It was likely known in antiquity, as well though.

Comment: Your equation "of unit cube" defines 8 points, not the unit cube.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I changed the description

Comment: Thanks Mark, but is there a solution in the context of my limited definition of quality? It merely requires the coordinate lines on the cube to be stretched/compressed uniformly.

Comment: @HarryvL I don't understand your definition of $Q$. What do you mean by a "great circle"? Here's my guess. We intersect the surface of the cube with a plane that is parallel to one of the faces of the cube; this gives us a square $S$ on the surface of the cube that runs all the way around the cube. Then we map $S$ to the sphere, and the image of $S$ on the surface of the sphere we call a "great circle." Is this correct? Note that this is not what is usually meant by a great circle on the surface of a sphere.

Comment: Hi Timothy, you are right. That’s what I meant. And the quality then becomes the uniformity of the map of those squares (or what I call coordinate lines in my response to Mark).

Comment: The description still looks like 8 points to me. Maybe you want {(x,y,z) ∊ ℝ^3  | max{|x|, |y|, |z|} = 1}.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I have updated the description slightly.

Comment: Do you care more about length distortion or "ratios of length distortion"?  Also, how do you define "most distorted great circle"? (If it is in terms of Q, then your exposition is a tiny bit circular... no pun intended.)

Comment: Sam, I want to make the grid points on a “great circle” (in the meaning discussed with Timothy) equidistant. At the moment some “great circles” are worse than others.

Comment: When you claim your quality is $96\%$, is that for the $p=50$ example you gave? Did you seek to optimize $p$?

Comment: That is for the 9x9x9 grid and p=50. However, for this grid any even p>=16 will achieve better than 96.0 quality. The best I can achieve for this grid is 96.1 for p>=24. For a finer grid, a larger p is required to deal with deteriorating quality near the edges of the cube.

Comment: Interesting formula / algorithm. How did you derive it? Also, it seems to me that the larger $p$ is, the better the quality becomes. Is that so? If so, have you considered deriving a formula for the limiting case for which $p\to\infty$?

Comment: It is explained here: https://hvlanalysis.blogspot.com/2023/05/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html?m=1

Comment: I see. But I don't understand the rationale for making the method iterative. According to the reasoning on your blog, if we consider the line on the cube where $y=0$ and $z=1$, shouldn't the "optimal" image point on the cube be $x_c=\sqrt{y^2+z^2} \tan\left(x \arctan\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\right)\right)=\tan\left(x \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$ and $y_c=y=0$ and $z_c=z=1$? Because this would be achieved in the very first iteration, in the limit when $p\to\infty$, and if you iterate further on that, you're just going to move away from that ideal point, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: And instead of using $x_c=\sqrt{x^p+y^2+z^2} \tan\left(x  \arctan\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^p+y^2+z^2} } \right)\right)$, why don't you just use $x_c=\cases{\sqrt{y^2+z^2} \tan\left(x  \arctan\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{y^2+z^2} } \right)\right), & |x| < 1\\x, & |x| = 1 }$?

Comment: Similar to Nowell, I wanted to come up with closed form expressions of the form  $\underline{x}_{sphere} =\underline{f} \left( \underline{x} \right)$. Hence the idea to include the power term to deal with the singularity. The central coordinate line and edges remain straight under the transformation  $\underline{x}_{c} =\underline{g} \left( \underline{x} \right)$ and the "quality" cannot be improved. However, elsewhere the iteration helps a bit. Since I was so close to achieving 100% quality throughout, I wondered if there was an alternative (closed-form) expression that would achieve this.

Comment: Why is it important that the expression is on a closed form?

Comment: You say that the quality of the central coordinate line and edges cannot be improved. However, my point was that I think the quality should get _worse_ after you perform additional iterations, since after one iteration, you should have obtained optimal quality for those lines, and additional iterations will move the points on those lines from their optimal positions. I'm still wondering if I'm missing something. It it possible that the quality will improve for some locations, but I at least think that the quality should get worse for the central and corner lines. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct for small p. It distracts from the central question though - can the mapping in the "interior" be improved further?

Comment: I wasn't talking about small $p$; I was talking about the case when $p\to\infty$. (For small $p$, you should reasonably get suboptimal positions after one iteration.)

Comment: You can perhaps improve the quality of the interior further, but I still don't understand the motivation for making the method iterative? If two iterations lead to better quality than one, what is your intuition for why that works?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{p \to \infty} x^p = \begin{cases}0&for\ \left\vert \text{} x\right\vert <1\\ 1&for\ \left\vert \text{} x\right\vert =1\end{cases}$ so it is a (clunky) substitute for the simple test and (at least in the limit) the quality at the central line and edges is not affected.

Comment: Without iteration and large enough p (or test for singularity) the worst quality I get is 95%. This is already a major improvement over Nowell and brute contraction. I tried the simplest iteration I could come up with just to see if it would give further improvement (which it does).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this link might bring some light on the subject, the equi-angular cube mapping might be what you are looking for:

https://blog.google/products/google-ar-vr/bringing-pixels-front-and-center-vr-video/

Comment: Thanks @user 1277628. However, the mapping I am looking for is neither area nor angle preserving. I only require equidistant points on the cube's coordinate lines to be mapped to equidistant points on the sphere's coordinate lines (as per the original query and pictures). Also see: https://hvlanalysis.blogspot.com/2023/05/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html

Comment: @HarryvanLangen Do you allow different coordinate lines to be mapped onto the sphere with different scaling factors, i.e. so that their corresponding curves on the sphere have different lengths?

Comment: Yes @HelloGoodbye. Have a look at the last figure. The map of the central coordinate line is longer than that of the edges by a factor $\frac{\pi }{4} /arctan\left( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2} \right)$